# Javascript check if transparent image on canvas has been clicked

Tags: javascript, canvas, click

I have a canvas, and I drew an image that is transparent, and has a polygon like shape. Now I need to check if that image has been clicked.

I have the cords 
{
x:30,
y:20,
w:100,
h:100
}

I could check for a box or circle Click but what if it is rigid like a polygon is there a pixel click test or the convex algorithm(But I don't want to have to specify the edges)?

Thank You.

Comment: While your question says you don't want to specify edges, it is quite easy to hit-test any shape (even transparent shapes) using `context.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to implement pixel detection with a secondary canvas to be used as a map.

1. Draw your shape onto your scene canvas.
2. Draw the exact shape onto a second canvas, but set the color to rgb(0,0,0).
3. Store that color as a reference in some sort of map to reference your first 'shape'

e.g.

```
var pixelMap = {
  '000' : 'rectangle 1',
  '001' : 'rectangle 2'
};
```

Every time you draw a new shape to the canvas, increase the rgb by 1. Unless you have over 16.7 million shapes (256^3), this method should suffice.

Heres an example implementation : https://jsfiddle.net/mikeschultz/nbtnxpf2/

Comment: Solves the question -- upvote. Adding a new canvas for each shape is a bit expensive. You might reduce the memory footprint of your solution by using an array of alpha values instead of a whole canvas since you just need to test transparency and not RGB. :-)